# how to get the existed wireless network characteristics and the activity executed once only

Tags: java, android

**Hello,
I create an activity to get the existed wireless network characteristics. The next code execute and give me the desired result. 
But this activity execute repeatedly. Have you an idea how to get the existed wireless network characteristics and the activity executed once only.**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View ;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
    TextView mainText;
    TextView number;
    WifiManager mainWifi;
    WifiReceiver receiverWifi;
    List<ScanResult> wifiList;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     String klm="";
    public static List<String> WiFiNetworks;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mainText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);
        String str = getNetwors();
        System.out.println("==================>"+ str);
    }
    public  String getNetwors(){
        String messageContent = "";
        mainWifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        receiverWifi = new WifiReceiver();
        registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        mainWifi.startScan();
        if(mainWifi.startScan()){
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                messageContent = extras.getString("Number");
            }}
        return messageContent;
    }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Refresh");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        mainWifi.startScan();
        mainText.setText("Starting Scan");
        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }
    protected void onPause() {
        unregisterReceiver(receiverWifi);
        super.onPause();
    }
    protected void onResume() {
        registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));

        super.onResume();
    }
    class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            wifiList = mainWifi.getScanResults();
            WifiInfo wifiInfo = mainWifi.getConnectionInfo();

            //getScanResults
            for(int i = 0; i < wifiList.size(); i++){
                sb.append(new Integer(i+1).toString() + ".");
                sb.append((wifiList.get(i)).toString());
                sb.append("\\n");
                String Capabilities =  wifiList.get(i).capabilities;
                if(Capabilities.contains("WPA"))
                {
                    WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration = new WifiConfiguration();
                    int stat= wifiConfiguration.status;
                    String key = wifiConfiguration.preSharedKey;}
            }
            klm = String.valueOf(sb);
            Intent i = new Intent(c, MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("Number", klm);
            mainText.setText(klm);
            c.startActivity(i);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why starting MainActivity activity inside onReceive method again?

Comment: to get the scanned networks characteristics from a class extends BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: if commanting `c.startActivity(i);` then what problem getting?

Comment: str value is null. I haven't the resul

Comment: The problem is obviously that you keep starting BroadcastReceiver from your MainActivity, but in your BroadcastReveiver's `onReveive()` you keep starting the MainActivity, thus creating the loop... Maybe, you could try creating a global variable to remember the "Number" and use it in the MainActivity?

Comment: Have an idea concerning the detect of the existed wireless network characteristics.